# How to change/give user agent definition to phantomjs from cmd

Tags: amazon-ec2, phantomjs

How can I give user agent definition to **phantomjs**, I am currently running using following command on *aws* server *ec2* instance

```
phantomjs --web-security=no --ssl-protocol=any --ignore-ssl-errors=true driver.js http://example.com
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a user agent in PhantomJS only in script (driver.js in your example). The documentation about it: http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/property/settings.html

If you want to pass user agent to PhantomJS in a command line, you can use a parameter. In the script you can take the parameter and set it as a user agent. You can try an example below:

```
var webPage = require('webpage');
var system = require('system');

var page = webPage.create();

var userAgent = system.args[1];

page.settings.userAgent = userAgent;

console.log('user agent: ' + page.settings.userAgent);

phantom.exit();
```

Running it as follows:

> $ phantomjs ua.js "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64)
>   AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120
>   Safari/537.36"

you will get output:

> user agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36
>   (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/37.0.2062.120 Safari/537.36

Comment: Thanks a-bobkov for your answer, it worked for me. Thanks a lot.